# Can I nest (combine) two Entities that share same roles? ORM

Tags: database, orm, binary, entity, ternary

I am super beginner of IT and currently studying very basic of `ORM` before studying `mysql`.

My question is as the title said, is it possible (correct) if I combine the roles (binary boxes) because they have same roles which is 'studied in'. Actually I'm not sure they are binary relationships. Should I modify as Ternary?

Thank you a lot in advance.

Take a look at this [reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdz6u.png).

Comment: Do you need further help or did my answer solved your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, it is called `many-to-one` or `one-to-many` relations, where A contains multiple instances of B, but B contains only one instance of A.

For further understanding I suggest to take a look at this [documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations).

The example is made with an `User` and a `Photo`.